# Python to Facebook message, no xmpp authorisation

Tags: python, facebook, xmpp

I am trying to develop a python script that will automatically send a private facebook message to one user.

I have followed the procedure [here](https://philsturgeon.uk/python/2013/06/03/facebook-message-with-xmpp-access-tokens-python/) but this uses the xmpp access tokens.
From what I have read, this is no longer supported.
Does anyone know of a suitable work around?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only send messages with the official ways (Send Dialog, Facebook Messenger, ...).

Take a look at the Send Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Most likely it´s what you need.